# Does Nimbus Look and Feel work on all platforms (even if the jar is converted into an exe)?

Tags: java, look-and-feel, nimbus

I'm using the Nimbus look and feel in a Java application I am building and have a safeguard in case Nimbus can't be found but it doesn't look very good and much of the components look obstructed when using the default Windows look and feel. I found some things saying that Nimbus was cross-platform so I think it should be okay but I came here just in case. When I say jar converted into exe I'm just talking about compiling it into a jar and then creating a self-contained executable out of it, would that have Nimbus look and feel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since the Nimbus look and feel is cross-platform and has been included since Java 6, the JAR file will also have it once executed.

One way you can be reassured of it is by following the instructions on how to set in the official documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html